# Setup analytics goal where user originated from a particular url

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking, goal-tracking

We want to create a checkout goal in Google Analytics that is only triggered when the user came to our site from a specific url.

E.g. our site www.buysomething.com is an ecommerce site that sells 1 product. We want to know how many people completed the purchase after arriving on our site from www.partnersite.com (a 3rd party site we do not own).

Here's an example scenario:
* user goes to partnersite.com
* user clicks a buy now button on partnersite.com
* the user is taken to our website buysomething.com (either in an iframe or a new window)
* the user completes the purchase

We're not interested in how many people bought the item, only how many people came from partnersite.com and purchased the item.

Comment: A goal might be necessary to get that information - if you apply a segment "campaign source starts with partnersite.com" you get all your reports for the subset of users that came via that site. You can even use this to create audiences for e.g. Adwords, so the added value of a goal is by now kind of limited.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1: Segment

Like Eike mentioned in his comment, you could use a generic goal of all purchases and then segment to that referral source. This would be useful if you need to get historic data from your current analytics.

If you have many different individual referrers that you need to track, this may be the best option.

An alternative to this option would be to create a custom report with a secondary dimension of referrer (you can also filter individual custom reports). This could help if you have multiple individual referrers and don't want to have tons of segments or constantly be editing them.

#### Option 2: View

Create a new View in your property that filters traffic to only show data from that specific referral. Then, create a goal (same as above) and now not only are your goals specific to that referrer, but **all** of your reports data will be specific to that referral source. Note: This would only have data after it is created (it would not have historic data like a segment would).

If this referral source is truly that important to the data insight of your website, this is the option I would use. Just keep in mind that this view now needs to be managed in addition to any other reporting views you have on the site.